# Change Google Play password without changing Google Account password

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, password

Is this possible? I want to just change my Google Play password without changing my password for every other Google product.

Basically I want to allow a friend to log-in to some of my mobile game accounts, but not give them access to my entire gmail/google account..

Comment: That isn't possible, Google Play is tied to your Google account, so changing your password affected all Google products you're signed into.

Comment: The google ecosystem is meant to work across the board. Any change you make to any google service you're linked to spread across the board to all other services. Fun note: I read about a guy who for fun changed his YouTube name (to something obscene and embarrassing )and later on sent an email to his work mates and family only for him to later notice his name on email had changed to the new obscene name. context-> it takes sometime for this change to be effected across other services

Answer (score 1):

Quick Answer: No

Your Google Play store account is tied to your Google Account if you'd like to share it with someone you'll have to share your Google Account. There is no such thing as a Google Play store account only a Google Account.